# Github: View feature branches unique to this fork (not in upstream)

Tags: git, github

I've forked a repository on Github that I would like to contribute to. I've already developed several features as feature branches. On my local machine, I can view the list of feature branches I've written by doing `git branch`. What is the equivalent way to view a list of feature branches in my fork on Github? If I just view the list of branches, every branch from both the upstream and the origin is in the list.

Another scenario: I am examining somebody's fork of a porject, and I want to know what features they have added or what they have done differently from the original (`upstream`) repository. How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075184/git-list-of-branch-names-of-specific-remote

Comment: Is there a way to do this online, not locally?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the equivalent way to view a list of feature branches in my fork on Github?

Online (as opposed to my [old answer with local command `git ls-remote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076537/6309)), you would simply click on the `branches` link of your fork.
for instance:

https://github.com/rratliff/gnucash/branches

That supposes you have [pushed all your local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886153/6309).

> I am examining somebody's fork of a project, and I want to know what features they have added or what they have done differently from the original (upstream) repository

Again, "Branches" link will show you the user **[branches being "ahead"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6643415/6309)** the ones cloned from the fork.

But that also supposes that user has fetched from the original repo and pushed those updated branches to his/her fork, in order to have an accurate vision of his/her own feature branches.
Otherwise, you would see feature branches "ahead by 3 commits" of an original branch, except it is an old version of said original branch, fetched many month ago while that same original branch may have seen new commits on the original repo.

Comment: Hmm. I see "Showing 74 branches not merged into trunk" and "3 branches merged into trunk" This adds up to 77, but according to my repository I have 85 branches (these would be the 77 plus the 7 feature branches I've pushed.) This is sounding more like I have a github support question, not a StackOverflow question.